# Recursive function to get filesize in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems

I am working on a PHP function that will scan a given folder and return the total size of all the files in the folder. My issue is that, even though it works for files stored in the root of that folder, it doesn't work for files in any subfolder. My code is:

```
function get_total_size($system)
{
    $size = 0;
    $path = scandir($system);
    unset($path[0], $path[1]);
    foreach($path as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($file))
        {
            get_total_size("{$system}/{$file}");
        }
        else
        {
            $size = $size + filesize("{$system}/{$file}");
        }
    }
    $size = $size / 1024;
    return number_format($size, 2, ".", ",");
}
```

I'm unsetting the 0th and 1st elements of the array since these are the dot and the double dot to go up a directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this procedure. When you check this file is_dir then you have to count the file size also. And when you check is_dir you have to concat it with root directory otherwise it show an error.

```
function get_total_size($system)
{
    $size = 0;
    $path = scandir($system);
    unset($path[0], $path[1]);
    foreach($path as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($system.'/'.$file))
        {
            $size+=get_total_size("{$system}/{$file}");
        }
        else
        {
            $size = $size + filesize("{$system}/{$file}");
        }
    }
    $size = $size / 1024;
    return number_format($size, 2, ".", ",");
}
```

I think it will work fine

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to count the size of the subfolders. you have to add it to the `$size` variable.

```
function get_total_size($system)
{
    $size = 0;
    $path = scandir($system);
    unset($path[0], $path[1]);
    foreach($path as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($file))
        {
            $size += get_total_size("{$system}/{$file}"); // <--- HERE
        }
        else
        {
            $size = $size + filesize("{$system}/{$file}");
        }
    }
    return $size;
}
```

This might however give a problem because you are using the `number_format` function. I would not do this and add the formatting after receiving the result of the `get_total_size` function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursive directory iterator for the same. Have a look on below solution:

```
<?php
$total_size = 0;
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/directory/path');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
   if($file->isFile()) {
        echo $filename . ' - ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';
        $total_size += $file->getSize();
    }
}

echo $total_size; //in bytes
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `recursiveIterator` family of classes could be of use to you.

```
function filesize_callback( $obj, &$total ){
    foreach( $obj as $file => $info ){
        if( $obj->isFile() ) {
            echo 'path: '.$obj->getPath().' filename: '.$obj->getFilename().' filesize: '.filesize( $info->getPathName() ).BR;
            $total+=filesize( $info->getPathName() );
        } else filesize_callback( $info,&$total );
    }
}
$total=0;
$folder='C:\temp';
$iterator=new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST );
call_user_func( 'filesize_callback', $iterator, &$total );

echo BR.'Grand-Total: '.$total.BR;
```